# iOS - ViewController access into a cocoa touch class

Tags: swift

I have been working on an app, and I have a cocoa touch class file called Tiles. Inside this class I have applied sizeConstraints to each of my tiles. I started off to set these sizeConstraints as a constant, so it would work on a certain device. I made sure it worked on that device, then I decided I would then change the constant to zero, and set it as a multiplier of a UIView inside my ViewController. Inside my ViewController I have a containerView, it is just a UIView that is going to hold my tiles. The problem is, I am unable to access the containerView inside my Tiles class and therefore can not assign each Tile to be of a certain multiplier of my containerView. I do the positionConstraints inside my ViewController, which is simple to do and has been done, but to get the exact size of the actual Tiles is not working for me. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Your question is worded strangely and it's a bit hard to figure out what you're asking.

I THINK you are saying that you have a parent view controller that has one or more container views that host other child view controllers, linked with embed segues. Your child view controllers will be responsible for "tiles" of your parent view controller's window.

Further, you want your child tile view controllers to have access to the container view that they are contained in. 
Is that right?

If so, the short answer is "don't do that." You should treat another view controller's views as private.

What you *should* do is build a protocol that your parent view controller can use to communicate with the tile view controllers. Say you give each tile view controller a property "tileHostVC" that conforms to a protocol `TileHostVCProtocol`.

Then in the prepareForSegue method of your parent view controller, check for the identifiers of your embed segues, and you see one, set up the tile's tileHostVC property.

Now, in your tile VCs, you can send messages (defied in your `TileHostVCProtocol`) to the host view controller to ask it questions or request services.

Comment: I changed the wording, so maybe you can understand.